# setting httpCookies on IIS8 in Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, iis-8, azure-webapps

After security scan we've got suggestion to set the following in `web.config` to secure cookies

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
```

Unfortunately it seems this element is [supported in IIS6 only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228262(v=vs.85).aspx), while we're using IIS8 (through Azure Web Apps). After looking through [system.webServer child elements](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver) I don't see anything similar to `httpCookies`.

So now I wonder - how to enable HttpOnlyCookies through web.config in IIS8? Is it possible at all?